# Trouble resolving a singleton from the service container

Tags: php, reflection, singleton, laravel-5

I've created a ServiceProvider in Laravel5 that registers two singletons to the service container:

#### ServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\Passwords\FileMakerPasswordBroker;
use App\Services\Passwords\FileMakerTokenRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FileMakerPasswordResetServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $defer = true;

    public function provides(){
        return ['fm.password','fm.password.token'];
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerPasswordBroker();
        $this->registerTokenRepository();
    }

    protected function registerPasswordBroker(){
        $this->app->singleton('fm.password', function ($app){
            return new FileMakerPasswordBroker;
        });
    }

    protected function registerTokenRepository(){
        $this->app->singleton('fm.password.token', function ($app){
            return new FileMakerTokenRepository;
        });
    }
}
```

I've just started so the two concrete classes being created are just empty class declarations:

#### TokenRepository

```
namespace App\Services\Passwords;

class FileMakerTokenRepository {

}
```

#### PasswordBroker

```
namespace App\Services\Passwords;

class FileMakerPasswordBroker {

}
```

And I've registered my service provider in my `config/app.php` class:

#### app.php

```
...

   'providers' => [

        ...
        App\Providers\FileMakerPasswordResetServiceProvider::class

...
```

The problem is, I can't resolve the singletons out of the service container:

#### A dev controller

```
...

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class DevController extends Controller
{

    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app){
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function testPasswordReset(){
        // This throws an error
        return $this->app->make('fm.password.token');
    }

    ...
```

When I try to make the singleton, I get the error

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 736:
>   Class fm.password.token does not exist

I walked back through the documentation on binding and resolving from [the service container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container) and it looks like everything is right, but I'm obviously missing something.

Is there a step I'm missing or something I'm missing re: resolving a singleton from the service container?

### Update

Here's a screen shot of the stack if that helps:

[image: Error Stack]

Another interesting fact: When I dump the application to the browser from the dev controller:

```
dd($this->app);
```

And look at the list of service providers, the `FileMakerPasswordResetServiceProvider` class is not present:

[image: Missing service provider when dumping app]

The provider is eventually going to be deferred, but at the moment I have the deferred property commented out, so (as far as I know) it should be getting loaded. I see other providers that I've registered in the stack. This may be another clue.

Comment: I know doesn't make perfect sense but have you tried to put: 
use App\Services\Passwords\FileMakerPasswordBroker;
use App\Services\Passwords\FileMakerTokenRepository;

Into the dev controller?

Comment: Gave it a try: same error :/

Comment: Gave it a try: works. Maybe some caching issue? Run "php artisan cache:clear" and "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: Hmm, I tried clearing the cache and I got the error `[InvalidArgumentException] Cache store [cookie] is not defined.`. I do have the session driver set to cookie, but even if I change it back to file I get the same error.

Comment: I just tried restarting the entire web server (homestead) and still get the "class does not exist" error and the service provider doesn't show in the app dump

Comment: Woah, weird. I went into `config/app.php` and moved the `FileMakerPasswordResetServiceProvider`  up in the array, refreshed, and it works now. I don't want to put this as the correct answer because while it fixed the error I was seeing, it doesn't really explain why it's happening. I's still really like to know if someone cares to answer.